# Export results of Macrobenchmark in bitrise

Tags: android, gradle, bitrise, macrobenchmark

I am trying to run macrobenchmark in bitrise and I could do it with only gradle task which is:

```
benchmark:connectedAndroidTest
```

after I run this gradle task I can not see benchmark results in bitrise but in my local I can see that result file is inside of the:

> benchmark/build/outputs/androidTest-results/connected/test-result.pb
> file.

How can I export this result?

My bitrise workflow is something like:

[image: workflow:]

[image: export test result task config]

Answer (score 2):

The `Export test results to Test Reports add-on` step only supports JUnit XML test report files.

For other file types you should use the `Deploy to Bitrise.io` step which will make the file available on the build's page on the `Artifacts` tab. See the official guide at: https://devcenter.bitrise.io/en/builds/managing-build-files/build-artifacts-online.html#deploying-files-into-artifacts

[image]

Comment: do you mean those files will be available after i use this step?
because currently only apks files and mapping file are visible after running gradle task in artifacts section.

Comment: @Murat yes, the Deploy to Bitrise.io step can upload any kind of file. The guide explains in in detail but in short you can either move the files you want to upload to the directory specified in Deploy to Bitrise.io step (as you already have the step in your workflow, and it's uploading the contents of the default "deploy" directory) or you can add multiple Deploy to Bitrise.io steps and set separately the path it should upload (the path can be a file's path, then the step will upload that specific file, or the path can be a directory, in that case it'll upload the files from that directory)